# Laravel - Eloquent subquery filter rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, filter, subquery, eloquent

I want to get staff members whose `level` is equal to "Senior". I want to merge the user table with staff, as it carries the common information about the staff such as names, emails, etc.

Currently I'm using this in Eloquent:

```
$results = User::with(array('staff' => function($query) {
    $query->where('level', 'Senior');
}))->all();
```

If I run this I get all the users although **level** is not **equal** to senior, but I can see in the array staff object is empty.

Currently I do null checking to discard mismatching records.

Is there anyway to implement this in a better way, so when I filter something in sub-query, the main query will just return only the matching results array, so I don't have to do any null checking anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`with` doesn't change the `SELECT * FROM users` query. It runs another query to fetch related models: `SELECT * FROM staff` and applies `where` on this one.

```php
// this limits only related staff
$results = User::with(array('staff' => function($query){

  $query->where('level', 'Senior');

}))->get();

// this limits only users (it does not load related staff at all)
$results = User::whereHas('staff', function($query){

  $query->where('level', 'Senior');

})->get();

// and finally this will limit both users set and staff set
$results = User::with(array('staff' => function($query){
  $query->where('level', 'Senior');

}))->whereHas('staff', function($query){
  $query->where('level', 'Senior');

})->get();
```

Now, if you want to merge something, use simple join instead:

```php
// I dont know what relation you have, so I assume User belongsTo Staff
User::join('staff', 'users.staff_id', '=', 'staff.id')
   ->where('staff.level', 'senior')
   ->get( array('users.*', 'staff.level', ...) ); // select fields you need
```

Comment: how I can use the custom attribute in whereHas?

Answer (score 1):

Your where statement isn't exactly correct. You forgot the `'='`

```
$results = User::with(array('staff' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('level', '=', 'Senior');
}))->all();
```

Comment: You don't need `=`, it's default. However `all` won't work, since it's static method.